# Connecting to a web service using SOAP

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I am currently working on a node based application trying to make a request to a SOAP based service. I am making use of the node-soap module to work through this.
https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap

Currently i have the following implementation

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx?WSDL';
var appKey = 'ABYRCEE';
var xml = {
    appKey: appKey,
    mac: 'xxxxxxxx'
}

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    //console.log('Client:', client);
    client.getAllDocsisVideoInfo(xml, function(err, result){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }
    });
});
```

For the service to respond, i have a sample request in xml format, as the following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:doc="http://xxx.xxx.com">

   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>

      <doc:getAllDocsisVideoInfo>

         <appKey>"appKey"</appKey>

         <mac>xxxxxxx</mac>

      </doc:getAllDocsisVideoInfo>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see from the above that i have to pass in **appKey** and **mac** values and upon a successful request this will send back successful response in xml format with the appropriate response.

I am able to see **client** object return back with the appropriate functions, but upon calling the **client.getAllDocsisVideoInfo(....)**, i seem to see the following error

> S:Client: Cannot find dispatch method for {}getAllDocsisVideoInfo

I am not sure of the why? Is it because of the way i am passing in the xml object, how do i pass in the sample request?

Comment: Do a: console.log(client.describe()); To see if you get info about the client (methods, etc). If you don't get any info, I wonder if your url is incorrect somehow?

Comment: i tried that is gave me the necessary functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending hours on this and banging my head, i was able to get a successful response by overriding the namespace prefix, by removing the namespace prefix.

For example, the following object needed to be passed as

```
var xml = {
    ':appKey': appKey,
    ':mac': 'xxxxxxxx'
}
```

Instead

```
var xml = {
    appKey: appKey,
    mac: 'xxxxxxxx'
}
```

This piece of the node-soap documentation [https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#overriding-the-namespace-prefix][1] helped in figuring out the issue.

Comment: If that really solved your problem, please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the node-soap api:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

It looks like you have to call the function in the following manner:

```
client.getAllDocsisVideoInfo(xml, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader){

})
```

If you want to call it like you had it in your code, then I think you need to use the following:

Copy and paste from the API...

```
client.MyService.MyPort.MyFunction({name: 'value'}, function(err, result) {
      // result is a javascript object 
  })
```

Comment: so i figured out the issue with this, with assistance from a colleague and it was down to overriding the namespace prefix, when passing the arguments to the function